# retrieving data from session array in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have multiple checkboxes in my view as

```
<input type='checkbox' name='seats[]' value='$rowId$columnId'>
```

These are submitted to the controller and stored in a session

```
 $data['seats']=$this->input->post("seats");
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

Now how can I retrieve all the checked values one by one in my model.I want to store every checked value as a record in the database.

Comment: if you have found a solution, you should accept the answer or delete question to avoid further vote down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is

```
$array=$this->session->userdata('seats');
```

I would sugggest you to look at [userguide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) carefully before putting up a questoin

Comment: I've checked the userguide.But how can I retrieve each value of this array?Would I need a foreach loop?

Comment: Yes of course. wherever you have doubt about array use print_r($array) to print it and run for loop accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can set session data,

```
$this->session->set_userdata('Key','Value');
```

You can retrieve session data,

```
$this->session->userdata('Key');
```